# Ubuntu 16.10 unexpectedly installing zesty packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, do-release-upgrade, 17.04

I tried `do-release-upgrade -d` just to check if zesty was available. I don't want to upgrade for now. When do-release-upgrade asked if I wanted to continue I said no and it aborted. After a bit I did `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and now all of a sudden it's downloading a sh*t ton of zesty packages (I noticed they are zesty packages because they are styled like this `Get:1189 http://debian.charite.de/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 xorg amd64 1:7.7+16ubuntu2 [2.978 B]`, notice the word *zesty* in there?).
What do I do, I'm pretty confused. I DO NOT want to upgrade.

Comment: Does `/etc/apt/sources.list/` refer to `zesty`? You could change all occurrences to `yakkety` and do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` again.

Comment: @Jos You were right, they were referring to zesty. The problem is, after reverting to yakkety and upgrading, my packets did not downgrade. What's super silly is that the "details" built-in program says I'm in 16.10, screenfetch says I'm in 17.04, this is kind of messed up.

Comment: It is messed up, but is it workable? Does `sudo apt upgrade` work without complaints now?

Comment: @Jos Yes, but that's because I installed all ubuntu 17.04 packages. Do you know a why to downgrade automatically?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure there is no way to "go back" once you have upgraded to the next release. From experience I can tell you that you may see the odd bug here or there, but by the time the official release rolls out things will have smoothened out pretty well.

Comment: The 'Details' window giving the wrong version is normal by the way, I think it happens every time.

Comment: @Jos So your advice is to just stick with 17.04 beta 2 until the final version?

Comment: Yes, unless there is some package that doesn't work and that you absolutely need.